# Retrieving Data from Firebase Real time DB in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code snippet where I am trying to fetch temperature and humidity data stored in Firebase and store the data in two variables namely, temperatureValue and humidityValue but I keep getting stuck. Below is the code snippet

```
  double temperatureValue;
  double humidityValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    try {
      final data = await fetchDataFromFirebase();
      setState(() {
        temperatureValue = (data?['temperature'] as double) ?? 20.0;
        humidityValue = (data?['humidity'] as double) ?? 30.0;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle errors if any
      print("Error fetching data: $error");
    }
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchDataFromFirebase() async {
    final reference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
    DatabaseReference dht11Ref = reference.child("DHT11");

    DataSnapshot snapshot = await dht11Ref.once();

    if (snapshot == null || snapshot.value == null) {
      return {};
    }

    return snapshot.value?.cast<String, dynamic>();
  }
```

The errors I keep on getting revolve the following lines of my code

```
double temperatureValue, double humidityValue  DataSnapshot 
snapshot = await dht11Ref.once(); and return 
snapshot.value?.cast<String, dynamic>();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question to include the _complete_ traceback as _text_